# Copy rows from one table to another and add a primary key and date

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to copy rows from one table to another and in addition add a new primary key and system date.

```
INSERT into tableB (id, date, name, type) 
    SELECT id_seq.nextval, sysdate, name, substr(type, 1, 1) 
    FROM tableA 
    WHERE type != 'ABC' 
    ORDER BY name;
```

I get the error

> sequence number not allowed here

Not sure how and where to specify the new primary key. Thanks from a total newbie in the Oracle SQL world!

----> UPDATE: Final solution

```
 INSERT into tableB (id, date, name, type) 
    SELECT id_seq.nextval, sysdate, name, type1 
    FROM (SELECT name, substr(type, 1, 1) as type1 
    FROM tableA 
    WHERE type != 'ABC' 
    ORDER BY name);
```

Comment: You need to wrap it with subquery. From http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-02287 `The following are the cases where you can't use a sequence:

For a SELECT Statement:

    In a WHERE clause
    In a GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause`

Comment: Thank you!  Removing the ORDER BY clause fixed it!

Comment: Update:  After looking at the solution already out there, I modified my SQL to still order the data by using a sub query.