# INSERT from one table to another but assign new PRIMARY KEYs

Tags: mysql, insert, structure, primary-key, bulkinsert

I have two MySQL tables.

One is a large list of entries which is basically the main table. The second is a table of pending entries. Pending entries will either be merged into the large list of entries if they're approved, or get discarded without any change to the main table if they're not.

Both tables have an auto increment primary key and the exact same structure for all the other columns.

I use the primary key on the pending entries table for edits of the pending entries, but it doesn't matter beyond that point once it's approved.

I'd like to do an insert similar to this:

```
INSERT INTO `main_table` SELECT * FROM `pending_table`
```

It's super simple and easy! However, of course, there is an error:

> Error! Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'

At the moment, I'm using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO `main_table` (`col1`, `col2`, ..., `coln`)
SELECT `col1`, `col2`, ..., `coln` FROM `pending_table`
```

This can also work and is a bit shorter:

```
INSERT INTO `main_table`
SELECT NULL, `col1`, `col2`, ..., `coln` FROM `pending_table`
```

`col1`, `col2`, ..., `coln` represent all the columns except the primary key column, and I have to list them out one by one.

Of course, that query immediately breaks if any of the columns in the table ever change, and there's a really good chance I will want to add new columns in the future. It's pretty easy to add the same column to both tables. What I'd like to avoid is having to go into the PHP file(s) and manually add the column there as well in every place that it's used.

What I would like instead is to set so the primary keys on the `pending_table` will be discarded and replaced with unique primary keys that are unused in `main_table`. All the other columns will copy across. I haven't been able to find any option to do this.

- The [REPLACE command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replace.html) doesn't help because that's going to overwrite all the entries that already exist. I also couldn't find anything on the [DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE option of INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html).
- I found [a question here that might be asking something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41399126/merge-tables-and-assign-new-primary-keys-where-necessary) but I can't understand the solution proposed and I'm hoping for something simple. This one is [just a generic explanation of the problem potentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087715/how-to-insert-new-records-to-mysql-with-no-key-name-assigned-and-with-auto-incre). [This just seems completely different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66697848/mysql-insert-into-inside-update-and-set-new-primary-key-as-foreign-key) [as does this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36604184/copy-rows-from-one-table-to-another-and-add-a-primary-key-and-date). [This guy just made a mistake and he's already doing my "solution" above.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49669600/copy-row-from-one-table-to-another-with-a-new-primary-key) I haven't been able to find any other questions that seem related.
- I can make code to check the table structure and produce a dynamic column list. However, that just seems like a large kludge and I'm hoping to find a simpler and more elegant solution without adding/maintaining/running a large block of extra PHP code.
- I also thought of dropping the primary key column from the pending table and then reconstructing the whole table afterward, but that also feels kind of kludgey. I'm also not sure it would work because the column count would be different.
- Similarly, manually updating the primary key column by reading the main table ahead of time could work but also feels really kludgy. And it could run into problems (race condition) if some other process adds a row to the main table while those keys are being assigned.

Is there any simpler solution, or am I already doing the simplest solution?

Thanks for any help/ideas.

Comment: Why 2 tables , would 1 table with a status column not do?

Comment: Stored procedure with dynamic SQL. Gather the information about existing columns from INFORMATION_SCHEMA, build INSERT query text and execute it.

Comment: *At the moment, I'm using the following query: ```INSERT INTO main_table (col1, col2, ..., coln) SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln FROM pending_table```*. You may do not list destination columns - simply add NULL value for your `id` column:  ```INSERT INTO main_table SELECT NULL, col1, col2, ..., coln FROM pending_table```.

Comment: @P.Salmon I'd like to minimize the risk to damaging the main table data as much as possible. By the approval process, there is zero risk to the main table data until the merge query gets executed. In the best case, it's only a ton of skipped primary keys from inserted then deleted entries. In the worst case, the data being entered was wrong/missing and overwrites/deletes matching data in the main table, without any good way to keep track of the old and new values or preview before submission. This way I can preview all old/existing and new/pending before I commit any changes.

Comment: @Akina I think this is similar to my suggestion of dynamically generating the columns in PHP, but are you saying that can be done in SQL itself somehow with a query? Can you link some sources or terms I can find? Is it something like this? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171715/dynamic-column-selection-mysql

Comment: @Akina Also a good point that I can do the NULL instead. That's a bit shorter of a query, but it still has the problem that I have to dynamically generate the full column list, which means either a manual update each time a column changes, a dynamic update via PHP, or potentially your suggestion of doing via a complex dynamic SQL query.

Comment: Using an auto_increment to uniquely identify an entity/event/person is a terrible idea, in the absence of another way (based on entity attributes) of doing so perhaps a uuid might be better https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid. that way you could keep the model you have.

Comment: @P.Salmon Why is it a terrible idea? It seems to me that what you're suggesting with UUID could work - it would just use a lot of extra data per entry.

Comment: One thing I thought about with UUID - there are lots of cases where I'd rather not add a whole extra timestamp field (such as a table with millions of small entries) but I still want an easy way to find "new" entries. With auto incrementing, I can query for entries greater than the latest ID and directly get the list of what was added, while a random UUID would make such a query impractical. In this case, I do have a timestamp field, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

I did find one potential solution.

Rather than deleting the primary key column, I can remove the auto increment and index as follows. `id` needs to be the name of the primary key column and the type has to match:

```
ALTER TABLE `pending_table` DROP PRIMARY KEY,
CHANGE `id` `id` int(11)
```

From here, the primary key field needs to be set to NULL for the insert.

```
UPDATE `pending_table` SET `id` = NULL
```

Now, the insert will work without any error from duplicate primary keys.

```
INSERT INTO `main_table` SELECT * FROM `pending_table`
```

Then, we just need to restore the primary key in the pending table with this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `pending_table` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
CHANGE `id` `id` int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
```

It's not the simplest or most elegant solution in the world but it's all SQL, works regardless of the column structure, and it doesn't require any extra PHP to be maintained or updated.

Note that the pending table keys could be changed in the process.

Answer (score 0):

> It's super simple and easy!

No, as you've discovered it is not.

Leaving aside the primary key issue, this method (`INSERT INTO table SELECT *...`) is dependent on both tables having the SAME attributes, in the same order AND honouring the order of attributes within the table (which IIRC is not part of standard SQL). So while having to enumerate the attributes from both tables could result in undesirable consequences if the table structure changes, in the absence of a primary key there are several other things which can go wrong.

> I did find one potential solution.

It avoids the specific issue you encountered. But is not a good solution.

OTOH as presented it is an accident waiting to happen. There are no concurrency controls in your code to manage the safe transition of data from one table to the other. With concurrent access, there are race conditions where you will lose data.

As usual, the RIGHT way to fix this is to normalize your data - as per @P.Salmon's comment above.

IMHO the issues arising from assuming `SELECT *` are worse than those from enumerating attributes. Using `SELECT *` also has a performance cost (cache flushing, no covering indexes). So as a general rule, I always avoid `SELECT *`.

Comment: Thanks. "both tables having the SAME attributes, in the same order" is definitely the case here. For "honouring the order of attributes within the table (which IIRC is not part of standard SQL)" is this ever a problem in practice?

"There are no concurrency controls in your code to manage the safe transition of data from one table to the other. With concurrent access, there are race conditions where you will lose data." Can you explain? Is this like my adding a column at the same time as copying the data? Or is it something else?

Comment: "is definitely the case here" - for now. "ever a problem in practice?" - yes. "Can you explain?" - different sessions amending overlapping datasets at the same time.

Comment: "different sessions amending overlapping datasets at the same time"

So if two separate users tried to submit new entries at once? For this system it's only me using it. I'd have to think how that would be a problem still. I would assume that both inserts would complete, and certainly the resulting primary keys would depend on the order in which those inserts would happen, but how would the data be messed up? And why wouldn't the same problem happen even worse if both users are submitting all their entries live onto the main table?

Comment: Sounds like you've got some homework.